# Where should I save User data in the MVC paradigm so it's accessible at all levels?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

**Background:**

I am new to MVC and is just learning how to do things.

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to make User data available for all actions.

**How I am achieving it:**

I achieve this by loading User data in the *OnActionExecuting* function.

**The problem I ran into:**

I don't know where to store my User data and how to retrieve it at a later time (ie, during the action).

**Current Code:**

Here I am loading the current User.

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx) {
        base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);
        UserAccount user = null;
        using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext()) {
            user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.userName.ToLower() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower());
        }
    }
```

How do I get it in these places?

```
    public ActionResult Default() {
        ViewBag.Message = user.userName;  // ????????????
        return View();
    }
```

**Possible Solution:**

1. Just save it in a parameter.
2. User HttpContext (Not sure how this will work, please help).
3. User ControllerContext (Not sure how this will work, please help).
4. ViewState?
5. ViewBag?
6. Cache?
7. Any other type of MVC magic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make your controllers inherit some base controller class like that

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
```

then in the BaseController you are free to create methods or proerties that represent the User's data and they will be available in all actions of the AccountController.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
      public User CurrentUser
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.User == null || HttpContext.User.Identity.AuthenticationType != "Forms")
                    return null;
                if (Session["CurrentUser"] != null)
                    return (User)Session["CurrentUser"];
                var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity;
                var ticket = ((FormsIdentity)identity).Ticket;
                int userId;
                if (!int.TryParse(ticket.UserData, out userId)
                    return null;

                using (var db= new DbEntities(connectionString))
                {
                    Session["CurrentUser"] = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == userId));
                }

                return (User)Session["CurrentUser"];
            }

        set { Session["CurrentUser"] = value; }
        }
}
```

Comment: Further to this you could have a property in your `BaseController` that writes values to the session. That way your user info will be available for the entire session.

Comment: I have 2 questions:  Where do you get DbEntities or current context?  Where do you set it?  Also, how do I get the connectionString?

Comment: DbEntities is just for the example and it is a designer generated EntityFramework class used to access the database. You may want to look at EF as one possible ORM (Object Relational Mapping) tool to help you. You put the connection string in the web.config file and use System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YouConnectionStringName"]; to get it. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134260.aspx